# Prove that $A\ge0, B\ge0$ and $A\ge B$ implies $B^{-1}\ge A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

Does anyone know how to prove the following:

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are both positive definite and $A - B$ is positive semi-definite.
>   Show that $B^{-1} - A^{-1}$ is also positive semi-definite.

I really appreciate any comments!

Comment: Welcome to Maths Stack Exchange. The best way to get a really good reply is for you to tell us what you have already tried yourself. Besides it actually *being one of our rules*, it will also help anyone reading your question to get a better idea of what level you're working at. There are many ways to solve any given problem, ranging from the very basic to the basically incomprehensible. Best to give us an idea of where your at.

Comment: **Hint**: Notice
$$A \succ 0 \Rightarrow A^{-1} \succ 0$$
And analogous for $\succeq$.

Comment: Might have to do with the product $$A^{-1}(A - B)B^{-1}$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, can you explain further? I thought that the product of semi-definite matrices is not always semi-definite.

Comment: @AEdwards I made the comment without thinking it through. At this point, the comment is just an idle conjecture as to the intended method, possibly a dead end.

Comment: $M-N$ is positive definite if and only if

$$x^*(M-N)x \ge 0 \implies x^*Mx-x^*Nx \ge 0 \implies x^*Mx \ge x^*Nx$$

If you can show that $x^*Mx \ge x^*Nx \implies x^*M^{-1}x \le x^*N^{-1}x$, then you are done. Obviously this last step is the hard part, and I have to keep thinking about it... Maybe someone else will see the proof before me.

Comment: I spent the last hour on this and I am frustrated. I'll keep working on this. I did solve it for a special case when $A-B$ is positive definite. Then, I prove that the required quantity is also positive definite. Somehow, I need to incorporate non-trivial nullspaces. My proof falls apart when $A-B$ is singular.

Comment: Thanks all! What I have tried earlier was true only for A>B as well. There's this identity (derived from block matrices): (A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1} = A^{-1} + A^{-1}B(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1}, assuming that the corresponding matrix inverses exist. So it's not true for the case when A-B is singular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A\geq B$ implies that $I-A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}\geq 0$ and $A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}\sim A^{-1}B\sim B^{1/2}A^{-1}B^{1/2}$ and hence $I-B^{1/2}A^{-1}B^{1/2}\geq 0$ which implies $B^{-1}-A^{-1}\geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks, Pavel! This is such an elegant proof!

Comment: What does the $\sim$ mean here?

Comment: @Jasha Matrix similarity.